# Generate string subject to first two bytes of SHA256 of this string equal 0

Tags: linux, bash, random, sha256

I have a string `s` like:

```
username-password-{random}
```

I would like to generate the hash SHA256 of the string `s`, such that first 2 bytes of the hash equal to 0, like:

```
0000afcbd546843....
```

So, `username-password-` is fixed and we can random the `{random}` part, is there any way to control the `random` part to get the SHA256 satisfy that condition.

I have the code bash script below, but I have run many time, it does not meet the condition.

```
pt="0000"
counter=10000000
while [ $counter -le 20000000 ]
do
        echo $counter
        fibyte=$(echo -n ""username-password-"$counter" | sha256sum | cut -c1-4)
        if [ "$fibyte" == "$pt" ]
        then
                echo ""username-password-"$counter"
                echo =======================================================
                break
        fi
        ((counter++))

done
echo DONE
```

Comment: In principle you should not control it. But you can do the sha and the prepend your wanted string ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm did not get your comment! Can you make it clear!

Comment: Generate the hash, throw away the first four digits and prepend four zeros in their place.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with this? Your requirement makes very little sense.

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

An important and highly crucial property of a cryptographical hash is that the result of the hashing operation cannot be predicted from the input.  So no, unless somebody breaks SHA256, there is no way to control the output.

Trying different inputs until you get an output which meets your constraints isn't really feasible.  If your current code can generate 10,000 attempts per second (in reality it's certainly a lot less, but humor me), you would need to run it for 1.767e68 seconds which is ([Wolfram Alpha to the rescue](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2**256+seconds+%2F+(256+*+256+*+10000)) 4.1e50 times the estimated age of the universe to get the result you want, give or take a few universes.

Comment: There are probably no good reasons to do what you seem to be trying to do, anyway.  This is most likely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you *actually* hoping to accomplish with this?